# Как сделать этот код python асинхронным

Tags: python, asyncio

Объясните почему мой код работает синхронно, для ускорения запросов я использовал concurent.futures, я много прочитал про асинхронность , но не как не могу это понять. Объясните на примере этого кода.
Этот код работает очень медленно на обработку 20 запросов тратит "Func GET_DATA_FROM_API took 83.2843 for exution"

```
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from datetime import date, timedelta
from timeit import default_timer as timer

import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError


def add_data(route_dict, booking_token_list, json_response, use_date, key):

route_dict[key].append(
    (use_date, json_response['data'][0]['price']))
booking_token_list.append(
    ((key, json_response['data'][0]['booking_token'])))
return route_dict, booking_token_list


def process(query):

result = None
session = requests.Session()

try:
    response = session.get(query)
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
else:
    result = response.json()
return result


def thread_pool(process, query):
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(process, query)
    json_response = future.result()

return json_response

def get_data_from_api():

start = timer()

# parametrs
route_dict = {
    'ALA-TSE': [],
    'TSE-ALA': [],
    'ALA-MOW': [],
    'MOW-ALA': [],
    'ALA-CIT': [],
    'CIT-ALA': [],
    'TSE-MOW': [],
    'MOW-TSE': [],
    'TSE-LED': [],
    'LED-TSE': []
}

booking_token_list = []
use_date = ''
amount_of_days = 31
endpoint_get_data = "https://api.skypicker.com/flights?"
print('[INFO]: Start create request')

for key in route_dict.keys():

    lst = key.split('-')
    fly_from = lst[0]
    fly_to = lst[1]

    for day in range(amount_of_days + 1):
        use_date = (date.today() + timedelta(days=day)
                    ).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        query = endpoint_get_data + \
            f"fly_from={fly_to}&fly_to={fly_from}&date_from={use_date}" + \
            "&curr=KZT&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&partner=picky&v=3"

        json_response = thread_pool(process, query)

        if len(json_response['data']) == 0:
            continue

        route_dict, booking_token_list = add_data(
            route_dict, booking_token_list, json_response, use_date, key)

print('[INFO]: API connection. Success!')
print('[INFO]: Finish create data')
end = timer()
print(
    f'\nFunc took {round(end-start, 4)} for exution\n')
return route_dict, booking_token_list


def create_cache(route_dict):

cache = 'cache'

for value in route_dict.values():
    value.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

if not os.path.exists(cache):
    os.mkdir(cache)

csv_file = 'cache/low_price_calendar.csv'

try:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(route_dict)
    df.to_csv(csv_file)
except IOError as er:
    print(f"[ERROR INFO]: {er}")


def check_valid_ticket(route_dict, booking_token_list):

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

endpoint = " https://booking-api.skypicker.com/api/v0.1/check_flights?"
json_response = None
for items_in_tuple in booking_token_list:
    key, token = items_in_tuple
    query = endpoint + \
        f"v=2&booking_token={token}" + \
        "&bnum=3&pnum=2&affily=picky_{market}&currency=KZT&adults=1&children=0&infants=0"


    json_response = thread_pool(process,query)

    flights_checked = json_response['flights_checked']
    flights_invalid = json_response['flights_invalid']
    price_change = json_response['flights_checked']

    print(f'Flights_checked: [{flights_checked}]\
            Flights_invalid: [{flights_invalid}]\
            Price change: [{price_change}] {key}')

    if flights_invalid:
        print(
            f'[INFO]: Flights_invalid:{key} {flights_invalid}\n[INFO]: START update data ')
        route_dict[key].append({'flights_invalid': flights_invalid})
        create_cache(route_dict)
    elif not flights_checked:
        print('[INFO]: Not all tickets are confirmed\n[INFO]: START update data')
        check_valid_ticket(route_dict, booking_token_list)
    elif price_change:
        print(
            f'[INFO]: Price change:[{price_change}] {key}\n[INFO]: START update data')
        update_data = get_data_from_api()[0]
        create_cache(update_data)
        print(f'[INFO]:Update data finish')


def main():
    route_dict, booking_token_list = get_data_from_api()
    create_cache(route_dict)
    while True:
        check_valid_ticket(route_dict, booking_token_list)


main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Данный код не получится сделать асинхронным потому как используется синхронная библиотека, но можно выволнить несколько запросов одновременно через Executor

```
for key in route_dict.keys():

    ...

    for day in range(amount_of_days + 1):
        ...
```

Замените на

```
def process(keysdate):
    key, date = keysdate
    ...
    return key, result

keysdates = itertools.product(route_dict.keys(), range(amount_of_days + 1))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for key, result in executor.map(process, keysdates):
        route_dict[key].append(result)
```

Логику запроса перенесите в отдельную функцию, чтоб этот кусок можно было запускать отдельно.

itertools.product делает комбинацию из дат и направлений чтоб убрать вложенный цикл и пройти это всё одним мапом, но можно и без него обойтись.

executor.map выполняет одновременно 5 запросов, по мере ответов запускает новые запросы.

В конце собираем результат циклом в один словарь.

Чтоб сделать код асинхронным - нужно использовать асинхронную библиотеку, например aiohttp. Но у вас нет в коде ни тасков, ни большого количества соединений - и значит асинхронность не даст ничего.

Comment: Человек же хотел сделать код асинхронным, а не многопоточным.

Comment: @eri пожалуйста объясните, что делает этот код я не все понимаю просто, если можно по подробнее.

Comment: @BlueScreen - тогда надо будет писать новый код, а не этот)

Comment: Он просто зпускает вашу функцию в несколько потоков.

Comment: @eri def process(keysdate):
    key, date = keysdate
    ...
    return key, result      
эта функция у вас обозначает логику запроса?

Comment: где ... вставляйте логику

Comment: @eri извините я не могу разобраться я перенес вроде логику, изменил немного вывод хочу получить просто json_response и дольше уже обработать 
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
                json_response = executor(process, fly_from, fly_to, endpoint_get_data, day) 
но получаю ошибку TypeError: 'ThreadPoolExecutor' object is not callable

Comment: Давайте подождем ответа на aiohttp с полным кодом в примере

Comment: @eri Здравствуйте! Вчера я сделал через процессы, но не смог добиться асинхронности, пожалуйста  можете глянуть сказать что я сделал не так. Я обновил вопрос и код

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию `asyncify()` из библиотеки [`asyncer`](https://github.com/tiangolo/asyncer)